Как получить элементы crm.item.list по id смарт-процесса в произвольном блоке php кода?
Необходимо получить номера контактов в элементах списков смарт-процесса, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать в блоке php кода?


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Может там есть какая-то система параметров/аргументов...
